# How to provide shared link for Amazon Workdocs through rest api or client provider?

Tags: amazon-workdocs

Workdocs provides shared link concept on AWS but I didn't find any way to provide that programmatically.
Although it provides download url for the file which is valid for certain period, there is no parameter to set time period for the same neither the public or restricted access.